# Ember actions in views stopped working in version 1.7.0

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Today I tried updating my application to ember 1.7.0 but I noticed my action handlers in the views stopped being called.

My view is defined as follows:

```
// Ember view for the project partial
App.ProjectThumbnailView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'partials/_project',
  didInsertElement: function() {...},

  /**
  * Handles the event when the 'feature project' button is pressed
  * @param  {Project} project The project to be featured
  */
  featureProject: function() {
    var project = this.get('context');
    project.toggleProperty('featured');
    project.toggleProperty('abilities.feature');
    project.toggleProperty('abilities.unfeature');
    project.feature()
        .then(
            function() {},
            function(error) {
                project.toggleProperty('featured');
                project.toggleProperty('abilities.feature');
                project.toggleProperty('abilities.unfeature');
                App.set('error', {
                    message: I18n.t('error_message_generic_server')
                });
            }
    );
  }
});
```

The template partials/_project.hbs contains the following button to call the action:

```
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary right-top" {{action 'featureProject' target='view'}}><i class="icon-star"></i> {{unbound i18n 'feature'}}</button>
```

I also tried putting the featureProject action inside an actions hash to no avail.

This used to work perfectly in ember version 1.6.0 and before. Is there anything I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: can you put together a bin showing the issue? I made a bin and it seems to working fine. see http://emberjs.jsbin.com/meqef/1/edit

Comment: The problem is that my project is really big and that I can't seem to reproduce the bug with a small subset of code because the environment is different (modules etc,...).

Comment: hmmm.... Thats gonna be tricky to track down.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your actions inside an `actions` hash.  Ember 1.7.0 removes support for lookup of actions in the controller root object.  This has been deprecated for some time.

```
// Ember view for the project partial
App.ProjectThumbnailView = Ember.View.extend({

  actions: {
      /**
      * Handles the event when the 'feature project' button is pressed
      * @param  {Project} project The project to be featured
      */
      featureProject: function() {
        var project = this.get('context');
        // blah blah
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: based on this bin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/meqef/1/edit it seems that its just deprecated in 1.7.0 but should still work, so I don't think that was his issue.

Comment: You are correct- it has been removed entirely in `1.8.0-beta.1` but should still work as deprecated in `1.7.0`